# Upgrade from Angular 5.2 to 6.1

Tags: angular, webpack, angular6

I am upgrading to Angular 6, but it looks like i get an error when running ng serve or ng build.

I do get the following error

> Cannot destructure property 'createHash' of 'undefined' or 'null'.
>       TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'createHash' of 'undefined' or 'null'.
>           at Object. (C:\Users\stian\Source\Repos\minside\src\MinSide.Web\Areas\ClientApp\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\index.js:26:44)

I have been following the update guide https://update.angular.io/

It looks like it is webpack related, but if anyone know how to fix this or has experienced it themselves. Help is appreciated

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to update `wepback` from `^4.1.0` to `^4.3.0` or `^4.4.1`

Comment: I have not installed webpack myself, so its not in my package.json.      i do however see the npm package webpack version ~4.6.0 in node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/webpack and @ngtools/webpack@6.0.1 in node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack

Comment: @stian64 try ```npm remove webpack``` then
```npm install webpack@4.4.1```

Comment: When i try that, i get this outputted:                                               
                                                                                                                                              ERROR in ./src/main-accounting.ts
Module build failed: Error: Angular Compiler was detected but it was an instance of the wrong class.
This likely means you have several @ngtools/webpack packages installed. You can check this with `npm ls @ngtools/webpack`, and then remove the extra copies. Can i update the webpack ngtools have, or  any other option?

Comment: @stian64  would be good if remove node modules and package-lock.json and npm i again.

Comment: Worked great! Easy fix

Answer (score 5):

You need to Uninstall webpack

> `npm remove webpack`

and Re-Install `webpack`

> `npm install webpack`

Answer (score -1):

Remove ! @ # or ... From your folders name and install your node again > npm install

Comment: Please include details of how this would resolve the issue. The original question does not seem to have special characters in their path